# Metrics for time series segments

Tags: time-series, classification, intervals, metrics, segment

I am looking for a metric to evaluate a time series segmentation or classification task.

Suppose we have an ML model which tries at each time to classify a point as TRUE or FALSE.

All consecutive points with the same label (TRUE or FALSE) are grouped into segments or intervals we classify with the same label. So the whole series is a succession of TRUE and FALSE intervals.

We have a ground truth of the data already labeled and want to evaluate the model at segment level, with some tolerance about the intersection between the classified interval and labeled one (two intervals are considered as matching if they intersect each other for 70% of their total/union duration, IoU).

Is there any implementation of such metric in Python ?

Thank you

I have already computed and measured the IoUs of labeled Vs classified segments.